# General Form of Arima(2,1,2)

Tags: arima, autoregressive, moving-average

There is a question in my textbook that asks for the ARIMA(2,1,2) model. I get how to do the AR and the MA parts, but I'm having a little trouble understanding the differencing portion of the model. What I have right now is:

$x_{t} = \phi_{1}x_{t-1}+\phi_{2}x_{t-2}+w_{t}+\theta_{1} w_{t-1}+ \theta_{2} w_{t-2}$

Basically I have an ARMA(2,2) model right now. How do I add the differencing portion?

Sorry if this seems like a dumb question and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your original time series is $y_{t}$. You have to start by constructing the series of first-order differences $x_{t} = y_{t} - y_{t-1}$. Once you have this series of first order differences, you fit an ARMA(2,2) to it the way you have indicated.